# Drag&Drop implementation with standar input upload as well

Tags: javascript, file-upload, drag-and-drop, filelist, data-transfer-objects

I have to implement drag&drop upload with JS and Symphony. The backend part is not done by me and I have almost no control on it.

So far it uploads only the last files uploaded, either with drag&drop or through standard file input; what I need is that the user can upload files with both methods, then press the upload (submit) button and transfer all.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div id="drop-area">
    <form id="dragAndDropForm" class="my-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
        <section class="input-area">
            <div class="input-area-upload">
                <p>Upload multiple files with the file dialog or by dragging and dropping images onto the dashed region</p>
                <input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" name="images[]" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
                <label class="button" for="fileElem">Select some files</label>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="upload"/>
        </section>
    </form>
    <div id="gallery"></div>
</div>
```

and this id my JS:

```
let dropArea = document.getElementById('drop-area');
        let uploadInput = document.getElementById('fileElem');
        let uploadArray = [];
        const form = document.getElementById('dragAndDropForm');
        let transferVar = document.getElementById('fileElem');
        let formData = new FormData();

        ;['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
            dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, preventDefaults, false)
        })

        function preventDefaults(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            e.stopPropagation()
        }

        ['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(eventName => {
            dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, highlight, false)
        });

        ['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
            dropArea.addEventListener(eventName, unhighlight, false)
        });

        function highlight(e) {
            dropArea.classList.add('highlight')
        }

        function unhighlight(e) {
            dropArea.classList.remove('highlight')
        }

        dropArea.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);

        function handleDrop(e) {
            const uFiles = e.dataTransfer.files;

            transferVar.files = uFiles;

            handleFiles(uFiles)
        }

        function handleFiles(uFiles) {
            uFiles = ([...uFiles])

/*              uFiles.forEach(file => {
                formData.append('images[]', file.name)
            }) */

            uFiles.forEach(previewFile)
        }

        function previewFile(file) {
            let reader = new FileReader()

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            reader.onloadend = function() {
                const enclosure = document.createElement('figure')
                const img = document.createElement('img')
                const ul = document.createElement('ul')
                const fileProperties = {
                    "File name: ": file.name,
                    "File size: ": formatSize(file.size),
                    "File type: ": file.type
                }
                const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

                img.src = reader.result;
                fragment.appendChild(enclosure);

                if (!uploadArray.includes(file.name)) {
                    enclosure.appendChild(img)

                    Object.keys(fileProperties).forEach((key) => {
                        const fragment_li = document.createElement('figcaption')
                        const fragment_span = document.createElement('span')

                        fragment_li.innerText = fileProperties[key]
                        fragment_span.innerText = key

                        enclosure.appendChild(fragment_li).prepend(fragment_span);
                    })

                    uploadArray.push(file.name)
                } else {
                    return
                }

                document.getElementById('gallery').appendChild(fragment)
            }

            //console.log(uploadArray)

            function formatSize(size) {
                const units = [' B', ' Kb', ' Mb', ' Gb']
                const divider = [1, 1024, Math.pow(2, 20), Math.pow(1024, 3)]
                let multiplier = 0 ? 0 : Math.floor(Math.log(size) / Math.log(1024))

                let output = +(size / divider[multiplier]).toFixed(multiplier === 0 ? 0 : multiplier - 1) + units[multiplier]

                return output
            }

        }
```

I need to find a way to add to the **dataTransfer** both the files coming from Drag&Drop and from the upload input.

Thanks in advance for any help